# MS Teams - Deep link to custom personal app returns "Link not supported" in mobile app

Tags: microsoft-teams

Deep linking to custom personal app works great in desktop computer, but gets a "Link not supported" message from mobile.

Deep link: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/548325e1-4f06-42c3-a81e-03ed634aa4e2/66f115d3-dded-496c-a5e3-7499f3c3202f

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXtHr.png)

Answer (score 0):

There was a fix done for this issue in latest store app. It's working on IOS now. Please check.

Comment: @Andy C - There was a fix done for this issue in latest store app. It's working on IOS now. Please check.

Comment: Thanks so much, confirmed the latest update on iOS fixed this issue.

Comment: @Mamatha-MSFT, 
Could you update your answer accordingly please ?